# Overlay 2 images with Gnuplot

Tags: image, plot, overlay, gnuplot

I have a text file with data ordered as a matrix and a png file.
I need to overlay both of them with gnuplot and i cant find the way.
I can plot the matrix file but i have no idea what to do after that.

If someone can help me with that issue it will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance¡

Comment: gnuplot alone cant do that, you need to use some graphics software to combine the results.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to be a little more explicit about the type of plot you want to make. If, for example, you would like to plot contours of your matrix file over the png image, you can start with this:

```
set contour base
set view map
unset surf
splot 'image.png' binary filetype=auto with image, 'data.dat'
```

But you will probably want to adjust the colors (set the palette), positioning, and scaling.